# Progress bar not showing accurate progress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

In my app i am getting data from server and saving in SQLite table. i have to show the progress bar for this entire process. I wrote [myRequest setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView]; but it is working up to downloading the data from server only,it is not showing the progress for saving data in to the SQLite table. please help me. Thank you

Here is some code i wrote before calling the url,in the request finishing method i am saving the entire data in to SQLite.

```
if (!myQueue) 
{
  myQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init]; 
}
[myQueue reset];
[myQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
[myQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[myQueue setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: It would help if you showed some of your implementation.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  How would anyone know from your question where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASINetworkQueue will only update the progressView up to downloading the data from server, Because ASI classes are for making connection with server , downloading source , make a queue of requests etc.

After the class had informed you that data is fully downloaded ASINetworkQueue's work is finished and after that  it is your application's responsibility to show the progress of saving the data in db

Comment: I read about this after posting the question, but thank you very much